# Conditional NOT IN clause in SELECT WHERE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible in a stored procedure for SQL Server 2008 R2 to have a conditional `NOT IN` clause for a `SELECT` statement's `WHERE`? I have three tables, `Employee`, `TestingA`, and `TestingB`, where `employeeID` is a foreign key in `TestingA` and `TestingB`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [employeeID] [int] IDENTITY(9500,1) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [middleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [suffix] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [createdDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Employee_createdDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [employeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestingA](
    [testingA_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [employeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isComplete] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TestingA_isComplete]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [createdDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TestingA_createdDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestingA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [testingA_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestingB](
    [testingB_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [employeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isComplete] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TestingB_isComplete]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [createdDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TestingB_createdDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestingB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [testingB_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to do `SELECT` on the `Employee` table with a conditional `NOT IN` for its `WHERE` clause based on an input parameter for the stored procedure:

```
@Type nvarchar(50)
```

Based on the value of `@Type`, I want to do a `NOT IN` on `TestingA` or `TestingB`. So it's something like this:

```
select e.employeeId from Employee e
    where 
        -- If @Type = 'TestingA' Then 
        -- e.employeeID NOT IN (select ta.employeeID from TestingA ta)
        -- End
        -- Else             
        -- e.employeeID NOT IN (select tb.employeeID from TestingB ta)
        -- End
```

How would I do this in Transact-SQL? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select e.employeeId
from Employee e
where @Type = 'TestingA'
  AND not exists(select 1 from TestingA ta where ta.employeeID=e.employeeID)
  OR @Type != 'TestingA' 
  AND not exists(select 1 from TestingB tb where tb.employeeID=e.employeeID)
```

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStarostin. What does the `select 1` do?

Comment: Selected column list is ignored in `exists`. Some like to put there even `1/0`.

Comment: This works, @IvanStarostin. Thanks! A follow-up: What's the difference between `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Found the answer to diff b/w `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: OK. There is some performance and logical difference _possible_.

Comment: In most cases, I think it's safe to go with `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a stored procedure I'd do two statements (It'll probably improve performance)

```
IF @Type = 'TestingA' Then 
  select e.employeeId from Employee e
      where e.employeeID NOT IN (select ta.employeeID from TestingA ta)
else
  select e.employeeId from Employee e
      where e.employeeID NOT IN (select ta.employeeID from TestingB ta)
```

Answer (score 1):

use This

```
select e.employeeId from Employee e
where 
     e.employeeID NOT IN (case when @Type = 'TestingA' Then 
      (select ta.employeeID from TestingA ta)
     Else             
     (select tb.employeeID from TestingB tb)
     End)
```

You can use join also for the same query is given below

```
select e.employeeId from Employee e
left join TestingA e1 on @Type='TestingA' and e.employeeId != e1.employeeID 
left join TestingB e2 on @Type!='TestingA' and e.employeeId != e2.employeeID
```